# DataTable 1.9.3 searching issue - prevent Data Table from considering href value - 

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, datatables

In my project I've created a `dataTable`, Everything is working fine except one particular case.

While performing searching, my `datatable` is also searching the text inside the `href` with in the anchor  tag. But i don’t want to consider this case.

Hope you understood my issue. Any help will be much appreciated.

I'm using version **DataTable 1.9.3**

**My javascript** :-

```
$('#dataGrid').dataTable(
        {
            "aoColumnDefs": [
            { "sType": "html", "aTargets": [1] },
            { "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [0] },
            { "bSearchable": false, "aTargets": [0] }
            ],
            "bPaginate": false,
            "bLengthChange": false,
            "bFilter": true,
            "bInfo": false,                
            "aaSorting": [[1, 'asc']]
        });
```

Comment: is your example is similar to my jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/vedmack/EyZZ9/  ? cause in that jsfiddle when you search for co.uk the table removes them from search results... ?

Comment: @Daniel,i found it atlast, my scenario is exactly similar to ur fiddle, but the issue is  with latest version of datatable i used, to make it clear u can look into this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/Rds5T/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue finally, the issue was with the version of data table I applied.
I used one of the most latest version of data table - **DataTables v1.9.3** and got this issue.

I also checked with the their most latest one - **DataTables v1.9.4** and it also have the same issue. Both datatables consider the href value of anchor tag while searching.

Finally i went with the **[Datatable 1.9.0](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.3/jquery.dataTables.min.js)** version and now it is working as expected.

Thanks all for your help

Comment: You could also use `$.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(...
` like this http://jsfiddle.net/vedmack/GyJJ8/

Comment: May be but the basic issue lies with the version bug of DataTable rit!!

Comment: was it reported as a bug ? cause if not , eventually you might want to upgrade, and then...

Answer (score 0):

I can help with a workaround:

```
<a hhref='file.aspx'>... </a>
```

and

```
 $("table a").mouseenter(function() {this.href=this.attr('hhref')});
```

Comment: Seems you understood my situation, but this idea is not working in my case.

Comment: datatable do search in tag attributes ?

Comment: Actually no, but there latest version seems to be doing this!!